# Prove that the sequence is correct

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $x_1 = 8$, $x_2 = 13$ and

$$x_n = 7x_{n-1} - 6x_{n-2} \qquad \forall n \geq 3\,.$$

I am trying to prove that

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \; (x_{n}=6^{n-1}+7)\,.$$

**Base step:**

Put $n=1$ in $x_{n}=6^{n-1}+7$, we get: $x_{1}=6^{1-1}+7=6^0 + 7=1+7=8$.

Put $n=2$ in $x_{n}=6^{n-1}+7$, we get: $x_{2}=6^{2-1}+7=6^1+7=13$.

Thus, the result is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

**Induction hypothesis:**

Let us assume that the result holds for all $n \leq k$, i.e.,
$$x_{n}=6^{n-1}+7 \qquad \forall n \leq k\,.$$

We prove that the result holds for $n=k+1$, i.e.,
$$x_{k+1}=6^{k}+7\,.$$

Now, let $I$ be the expression
$$x_{k+1}=7 x_{k}-6 x_{k-1}\,.$$

**Induction Step:**

Since the result holds for $n \leq k$, we have
$$x_{k}=6^{k-1}+7 \text { and } x_{k-1}=6^{k-2}-7\,.$$

Putting these values in $I$, we get:
\begin{aligned}
x_{k+1} &=7\left[6^{k-1}+7\right]-6\left[6^{k-2}-7\right] \\
&=7.6^{k-1}+49-6^{k-1}-42 \\
&=(7-1) 6^{k-1}+7 \\
&=6.6^{k-1}+7 \\
&=6^{k}+7
\end{aligned}

Thus, the result holds for $n=k+1$. By strong induction method, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $x_{n}=6^{n-1}+7$.

Comment: There's a subtle thing you are overlooking.  You are assuming that $k+1 \ge 2$ in defining that $x_{k+1} = 7x_k + 6x_{k-1}$.  This is okay.  We have proven it for $n=1$ and $n=2$.  Now we need to prove it for the $n > 2$. and lets suppose we have proven it for all $n \le k$.  We need to prove it for $k+1$.  Now if $k+1 \le 2$ we have already proven it so it is safe to assume that $k+1 > 2$.  (But we can *not* assume $k> 2$).  Now the proof goes as you did (assuming your arithmetic is correct... I didn't bother checking that) and your proof is done.  Good job.

Comment: Well then, is my proof correct? Is there anything I can improve?

Comment: Seems like you have made a mistake when writing out $x_{k-1}$ in the induction step.

Comment: You have a typo/arithmetic error (double error cancel each other out) where you write $x_{k-1} = 6^{k-2} \color{red}- 7$ instead of $6^{k-2}\color{blue}+7$ (why *did* you type that.  Later you write $-6(6^{k-2} \color{red}- 7)= -6^{k-1}\color{orange}-42$ when $-6(6^{k-2} \color{red}- 7) $ actually is equal to $-6^{k-1}\color{purple}+42$ (but $6^{k-2} \color{red}- 7$ was wrong in the first place).   What you should have done is $x_{k-1} = 6^{k-2} \color{blue}+ 7$ and $-6(6^{k-2} \color{blue}+ 7)= -6^{k-1}\color{green}-42$

Comment: $x_n = 7x_{n-1} - 6x_{n-2} \implies( x_n-x_{n-1})=6(x_{n-1} - x_{n-2} )$ could be helpful